# Access vault credentials using API

Tags: python-3.x, vault

I am trying to access Vault credentials using Python API. I am doing something wrong as I always get access denied. I have used the following code:

```
def fetch():

    url1="http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/gcp/config"

    payload1={}
    headers2={
        'X-VAULT-TOKEN': 's.DsqQCKCY1JMhSe1k8A5rIyku'
    }
    try:
        response1=requests.request("GET", url1, headers=headers2, data=payload1)
        return response1.text
    except Exception as err1:
        return str(err1)

    url="http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/myengine/data/myspringapplication/staging"

    payload={}
    headers={
        'X-Vault-Token': 'myroot'
    }
    try:
        response=requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        return response.text
    except Exception as err:
        return str(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are sending a request that contains a payload you should use the POST method. I would write it like this. If that doesn't work since the payload is empty maybe it is the GET request method so try removing data=payload.

```
import requests

payload = {}
# https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/gcp
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/auth"

ses = requests.session()
ses.headers.update({'X-VAULT-TOKEN': 's.Ezr0s63KQhW72knZHCIkjMHh'})
try:
    r = ses.get(url, timeout=60)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print(r.json())
    else:
        print("bad status code", r.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    pass
```

**Edit**: changed the code with default URL for testing, and it doesn't need a payload. So GET request is O.K. and this returns data for me.

Comment: Post Method - TypeError: The view function for 'fetch' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.  Get Method - TypeError: The view function for 'fetch' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: is this Vault link https://www.vaultproject.io/?

Comment: It seems it is. Anyway, it is not a problem on the Python part. This is a server-side problem. Something is missing in the config file or the vault is not set properly.

Comment: I updated my answer, with a test code that works. Definitely, it is not a problem on the Python part.